# Parallax not working when being redirected from another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax, materialize

So I have an application that uses parallax and it is being executed once the document is ready

## Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  parallax();
 
});

function parallax() { 
  $('.parallax').parallax();
}
```

## navbar.html.erb:

```
<a href="/#about-us" onclick="parallax()">About Us</a>
<%= link_to "Why invest with us?", investor_portal_index_path %>
```

The problem is, when the page is redirected and you go back to the homepage parallax no longer works and the images aren't being loaded either. Is there a way to get around this? I tried calling the parallax function after an onClick event but that is not working either.

Thanks!

Comment: check browser **developer** tools console for errors that may shed some light on your problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can the parallax in the footer of the web app. So it would look something like this:

```
<footer
    <script function($){
        $(function(){
          $('.parallax').parallax();
        });
      })(jQuery);
    </script>
</footer>
```

Good luck!